# sunken border when background-color css specified - how to avoid?

Tags: html, css, windows

If I specify background-color in a style for a text input, for example through an error class as follows in css:

```
.error {
 background-color: #f88;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<p>
    Normal Input: <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>    
    Test Input: <input type="text" class="error" />
</p>
```

I end up with a sunken border effect when the class is applied and a flat effect when it's not, see the sample here:

http://jsfiddle.net/D4SEZ/5/

I've only tested in Windows so it may be a windows specific issue. Can anybody suggest a method to avoid this while retaining the "default" look of the controls? All I want is the background color without the sunken look.

I don't really want to explicitly style the borders, etc.

EDIT: Just to be clear of the issue, I don't want the sunken effect on the second input that I'm seeing as follows:

[image]

Comment: unclear to me.  you want it to no longer be an input looking box?

Comment: `.error{border:none;}`?

Comment: @Randy: See screenshot. I just don't want the sunken effect. This may be OS specific but it happens on Win7 and 8 where I've tested it.

Comment: @Vucko: I want to keep the flat border, just avoid the sunken effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is an issue on mac/chrome as well. The default input border appears to have some sort of special border. As it has a white background on the default version it is hardly visible, however it is there. Chrome inspector shows this:

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
padding: 1px;
background-color: white;
border: 2px inset;
```

To have a true, cross browser, consistent look, I think you will have to overwrite these browser default properties, dislike it or not. Should not be to hard however:

```
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1x solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Or something in that order. And perhaps you should apply it to `input password` and `textarea` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I thought that might be the case. I was hoping to avoid doing explicit overriding off all input borders, but as you say that might be the only way. +1 and I'll accept as answer later today if noone else comes up with an easy work around

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`border-style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style). Input elements generally have the border-style defaulted to `inset` which is what you're seeing.

If your intent is to have a solid style border, you should be able to just do:

```
.error{border-style: solid;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4SEZ/6/)

Comment: +1 for the info on inset, but this is still not ideal.  On firefox it creates a very indistinct border, in chrome a thick black border and in IE a thin but solid black border.  None of them seem to match the non-styled input. It is just confusing and surprising to me that applying background-color would change the look of the border. I guess this is why picking a css or ui framework (I'm using twitter bootstrap on another project) is good for getting around these sort of odd issues.

Comment: Yea that is kinda frustrating. You can avoid a lot of these issues by using something like Twitter Bootstrap, or just writing specific and opinionated css.

Answer (score 0):

To just address this specific problem precisely and to avoid overriding any other border width or colors that you might have defined for other inputs, you could just specify a css reset rule on border style for the inputs that accept text (`text`, `password`, `email`, `search`, `tel`, `url` and `textarea`)

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"], textarea {
    border-style: solid;
}
```